# Bitnami PHP won't evaluate from shebang

Tags: php, shell, mamp, shebang, bitnami

I'm trying to run a PHP script from the command line. When I use **Bitnami**'s php interpreter to run it, it works OK. For example, I have the script `test_php`, and its contents are

```
#!/Applications/drupal/php/bin/php
<?php print 'hello world'; ?>
```

If I run `/Applications/drupal/php/bin/php test_php` in shell it works fine:

```
$ /Applications/drupal/php/bin/php test_php
hello world$
```

But if I run `test_php`, I get:

```
$ test_php
./test_php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./test_php: line 2: `<?php print 'hello world'; ?>'
```

This only happens with Bitnami's location of PHP. The shebang works fine with the version that shipped with OS X.

Comment: Newline problem maybe? The first message speaks about an expected newline... Could you add a newline between the two lines just to check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPCS not running on the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786299/phpcs-not-running-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a newline problem.  Try running `dos2unix test_php` and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami doesn't execute php directly, so you need to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /Applications/drupal/php/bin/php
```

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841448/2779168