# Pear and PHP_CodeSniffer installation issues: not able to use phpcs from command line

Tags: pear, phpcodesniffer, vvv-wordpress

My setup: Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6, PHP 7.0.24-1+ubuntu14.04.1, PEAR Version: 1.10.5, I'm working on a local wordpress build using vagrant/virtualbox (vvv).

I'm new to pear and php_codesniffer and cannot seem to get phpcs commands to work. I've been trying to install PHP_CodeSniffer using pear:

My first issue is when trying to install PEAR. I follow the instructions: 
`$ curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar` & `$ php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar`. 
Then when I try to configure Installation base to /usr/local/pear and Binaries Directory to /usr/local/bin, I get the following error: 
`Unable to create PHP code directory ($php_dir) /usr/local/pear/share/pear.
Run this script as root or pick another location.`

I found others with the same error and saw this solution: 
`sudo php /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin` 
But this prompted an error: 
`Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar`

I then tried configuring pear using: /home/vagrant/pear. I was able to install PHP_codesniffer, when I use `pear list`, I can see php_codesniffer:

vagrant@vvv:~$ pear list
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.4.3   stable
Console_Getopt   1.4.1   stable
**PHP_CodeSniffer  3.1.1   stable**
Structures_Graph 1.1.1   stable
XML_Util         1.4.2   stable

when I run phpcs, I get the following message: The program 'phpcs' is currently not installed. To run 'phpcs' please ask your administrator to install the package 'php-codesniffer'

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786299/phpcs-not-running-on-the-command-line/11787140#11787140): which prompted me to: sudo pear config-set php_bin /usr/bin/php, then uninstall and reinstall codesniffer. Everything seems to work correctly, but when I try which phpcs, there is nothing.

I've installed and uninstalled pear a few times. When I try to uninstall, it says that pear is not installed, but when I do `which pear`, I get `usr/bin/pear`. It's a bit of a mess, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PEAR is way out of date for many years. You should be using composer nowadays:  `composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer --dev`.

Comment: @Tomáš Votruba, I followed your advice and used composer. I am now able to run ./vendor/bin/phpcs command. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Great job! That's awesome, I'll turn it into answer so it's easier to found.

Answer (score 2):

PEAR is way out of date in 2017.

**You should be using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) nowadays** instead:

```
composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer --dev
```

Then run like:

```
vendor/bin/phpcs ...
```

---

To get more details about PEAR timeout, there is [RFC about PEAR removal for PHP 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-pear-include-composer).